# error in using pgfornament package

Tags: errors, pgfornament

I hope that someone can help me about this:

I have installed all necessary files of `pgfornament` in `texmf/tex/latex` and `texmf/tex/generic`. But when I run even a very simple code (like one below), I get the error message (I have TeXShop in a MAC platform):

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.44 \tikzset
>
> ```
>          {pgfornamentstyle/.style={}}%
> ```

The code I used is (the one from the package documentation):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

\pgfornament[width = 2cm,
color = red]{1}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion? Please advise.

Comment: Compiles fine for me.  Is there an earlier error message in the log file? `\tikzset` is defined by the `tikz` package which `pgfornament` loads.

Comment: My impression is that you have a very old version of TikZ/PGF on your machine. What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andrew Swann. Below is the first error message I got: (/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarytikztop
aths.code.tex))) (./pgfopts.sty (./pgfkeys.sty (./pgfkeys.code.tex)))
(./pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.44 \tikzset
             {pgfornamentstyle/.style={}}%

Comment: Hi @egreg, I am using TeXShop Version 3.48.1 (3.48.1).

Comment: texlive 2007 is seven generations old.  I suggest you update.

Comment: @Yuce TeXShop is not the TeX distribution. Go to http://tug.org/mactex, download the MacTeX 2014 distribution and install it. Then run TeX Live Utility (in /Applications/TeX) and update the distribution. You'll (almost) never have to install packages manually.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. I decided to instal MacTex. It seems that it is the complete package. Thanks again.

Comment: @egreg, Thank you so much for your response. I am installing MacTex now. Cheers.